# php/mysql - only a fragment of a long text is inserted into DB

Tags: php, mysql, insert, fragment, longtext

In my code, I use the variable `$content`.
It's a text string with a length of ~200000.
`$session` doesn't matter in this case.
If i try to insert the following data, ...

```
$c = mysql_real_escape_string($content);

mysql_query("
  INSERT INTO data (time, session, key_, value_) 
  VALUES('".time()."', '".$session."', 'content', '".$c."')
");
```

...a new row is generated in the DB and `time`, `session`, `key_` and `value_` are written.
But when `$content` had a length of ~200000, the inserted text is only a fragment of the first ~1300 characters.
The field type is set to `longtext`, collation is `utf8_bin`.

If i choose `$c = strlen(mysql_real_escape_string($content));`, something about '200000' is written to `value_`.
There is no mysql_error in any case.

So why is only a "short" fragment of my variable inserted?

**edit:**

To avoid this problem, I used `base64_encode()`, to encode all data and the query did its job.

Comment: Can you give the describe result of the table?

Comment: As stated in the PHP manual for the [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) function: *Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.*

Comment: Describe result is:

    [Field] => time
    [Type] => int(15)
    [Null] => NO
    [Key] => 
    [Default] => 
    [Extra] => 

    [Field] => session
    [Type] => varchar(32)
    [Null] => NO
    [Key] => 
    [Default] => 
    [Extra] => 

    [Field] => key_
    [Type] => varchar(100)
    [Null] => NO
    [Key] => 
    [Default] => 
    [Extra] => 

    [Field] => value_
    [Type] => longtext
    [Null] => NO
    [Key] => MUL
    [Default] => 
    [Extra] =>

@eggyal: Thanks a lot, I'll try it.

Comment: Try again - this time just using html safe ascii

Comment: @eggyal:I tried MySQLi, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

check the type of the field in the database, what type are you using ?

Comment: The type is longtext, as the question says. But text, mediumtext and largetext don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set field type to `TEXT` .